# How do I add webkit-keyframes animation delay

Tags: css

Right now my code has the animation appear then it applies the 2 second delay then the animation runs.

**How do I keep the animation from first appearing before the delay and then the animation?**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

    100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInUp1 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp1;
  animation-name: fadeInUp1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode):

> The `animation-fill-mode` CSS property specifies how a CSS animation
>   should apply styles to its target before and after it is executing.
>
> **backwards**
>   The animation will apply the values defined in the first relevant [keyframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes) as soon as it is applied to the target, and
>   retain this during the [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) period.

```css
.fadeInUp1 {
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInUp1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
.fadeInUp1 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp1;
  animation-name: fadeInUp1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadeInUp1">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: That worked except that after the animation runs it disappears.  How do I keep it there?

Comment: @MonteOrganics OK, I didn't understand the problem. Use `animation-fill-mode`.